# Get most recently created object in a queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Attempting to get the most recent object in a query set and I keep getting error

> TypeError at / 'PostManager' object is not iterable

How do you do this without iterating?

```
class DashboardTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"
    context_object_name = 'name'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardTemplateView,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["title"] = "This is about us"
        return context

class MyView(ContextMixin, TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # mission_statement = Content.objects.filter(Content.objects.title == 'test')
        # context = {'mission_statement' : mission_statement,
        #           'content_list' : Content.objects.all(),
        #           'post_list' : Post.objects.all()}

        # context = {'content_list' : Content.objects.all(), 'post_list' : Post.objects.all()}
        home_list = list(Post.objects).order_by('-id')[0]
        context = {'content_list' : Content.objects.all(), 'home_list' : home_list.objects.all()}
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

> home_list = list(Post.objects).order_by('-id')[0]

Post.objects is the PostManager : it is not a iterable, you cannot list() it.

I guess what you are after is this:

```
home_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id').first()
```

The difference between first() and [0] is that first() won't throw IndexError if no result in query set, it will return None.

Answer (score 1):

A small paranthesis error on line below

```
home_list = list(Post.objects).order_by('-id')[0]
```

Change this to

```
home_list = list(Post.objects.all().order_by('-id'))[0]
```

An alternative one

```
home_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id').first()
```

Also calling objects method on home_list is not needed. Below would also work fine

```
context = {'content_list' : Content.objects.all(), 'home_list' : home_list}
```

Comment: You **absolutely do not** want to do `list(Post.objects.all().order_by('-id'))[0]
`. That queries *all* Posts from the databases, puts them into a list, then throws away all but the first.

Comment: Yep the alternative one mentioned is better. Did that just for the code of asker